# botframework get attachment api returns with 404 for old images

Tags: botframework

**Background**

We are using the following api to fetch image data uploaded from our user via bot.

The API reference is the following.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-attachment

And the use case is the following.

User pasted image along with text and send message to bot.
The following image is the [bot side].
[image]

We are fetch the pasted image data and show it on [our app side].
The following is our app side.
[image]

**Issue**

But we found that for the images uploaded [1 month ago], the API returns with 404 http code and we could not get image data anymore.
For the images uploaded recently, The api responsed with 200 and image binary data which we can take usage and show it.

**Question**

Is it possible that MS side put some restriction for pasted image that uploaded to botframework blob storage more than a month?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that the Azure Bot Service's Connector service is not a storage service. When attachments are sent to/thru the Connector, Azure will store the attachment for no more than 24 hours.

If you are needing to access attachments sent days/weeks/months ago, then you should utilize [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/#overview), or some equivalent service, to meet those needs.

Comment: Hi Steven
Thank you for your commnet.
That make sense!
As you have mentioned below, Does there offical reference for 24 hours?
>-Azure will store the attachment for no more than 24 hours.

Comment: No, it isn't specifically documented anywhere, unfortunately. Primarily, because it is subject to change.